# MySQL Where Clause By Last String

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

i have a some data code like this :

1. PR 00001J
2. PR 00001B
3. PR 00002B
4. PR 00002J
5. PR 00003J

how i can get data only **J** with where clause ? is it need something like regex ?

i've been try with this query but the output was `NULL`

```
SELECT MAX(request_code) as max_request_code FROM `request` WHERE RIGHT('request_code',1) = 'J'
```

anyone can help me out ?

Thank you

Comment: You have double quotes around the column name so it is treated as a string.  I vote to close as a typo.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the output still NULL ..

Comment: Your sample data is confusing. How many columns of data are in there?

Comment: Works for me in [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=wRnVmxxrby)

Comment: @Nick 2 columns, id and request_code

Comment: @danblack, sorry, where's the query ?

Comment: someone evidently wiped it.  Feel free to recreate example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0). Are you considering the maximum as 5 because of its '00003' value as a number or because of the text sorting order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have it like this

```
WHERE request_code LIKE '%J'
```

You can refer to this link http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/